# Why does Eclipse + ADT plugin keep the CPU at 100%

Tags: android, eclipse, cpu-usage, adt

The second I open up layout.xml file from a simple skeleton app in Eclipse example plugin, the cpu usage locks up to 25% IE. 1 full core. and it's been on like this for the last 30minutes I wanted to let him run a longer time because I thought it is working something in the background but it just keeps doing that.

I've tested this on 2computers so far and the setup is 
install Android SDK,
install Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, 
install ADT plugin: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
open new project, select a skeleton project for Android 2.3.3
and just open the layout skeleton activity and perhaps change to android 2.3.3 in the upper right corner and maybe setup to theme.black.noTitleBar.Fullscreen.

And now your processor should be hitting 100% ( on one core ) and should be locked like that from now on.

Is there any solution to this issue, because at home I only have 1 core and I can not work on anything.

Does any one have any clue as to why this is happening ?
http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20110517-gbr8-201kb

Comment: I have the exact same problem. On my dual core setup Eclipse pushes one of the cores to 100% and it never releases it. My eclipse version is 3.6.2 with the latest Android SDK installed. I tried to close the project but Eclipse still remains at 100%. Only restarting Eclipse helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm seeing the same issue so I filed a bug report at http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18865.

The Android team have now released a fix and it works for me.  You have to upgrade to the latest revision of each SDK module that you downloaded through the android tool.  The latest version of the ADT also has a number of fixed for long-standing issues.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer "Why" this happens. But I can say what fixes it.

I encountered this on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit. I had 100% cpu and eclipse hang when I switched to debug view - Eclipse was unusable and had to kill it. I found the below bug report

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34641

Following the comments there, I tried

> cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/modules
>   mv libgail.so libgail.so.moved

Eclipse did not hang (no 100% cpu) when I switched to debug view.

Comment: I believe this made my situation somewhat more bearable. Though yet the build process eats too much 350% cpu ( for 4-core ), the build itself finishes at last, at least.

Answer (score 0):

Start Eclipse with `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote` (put it into `eclipse.ini` or start `eclipse.exe` with this option).

When Eclipse runs, start [jconsole](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html) and look at the thread dump to see which thread hogs the CPU. It's the one which isn't `WAITING`. File a bug report.

Comment: There is like 10 of them in state "RUNNABLE" I can't figure out which thread is hogging the CPU

Comment: Probably all or some of them. Refresh the view to see if some of them drop out of the list. Also check the stack traces to see what they do. That might give you a hint. Are you on windows 7?

Comment: I've tried both enviroments, windows 7 64bit and XP 32bit both enviroments yield the same issue.

Comment: Okay, because if you add the Workspace to your Library in Win7, Eclipse gets crazy.

Comment: You can also profile Eclipse with JVisualVM.  It's much more powerful then JConsole and, at least on linux, you don't have to start the target process with any special arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was resolved just by moving my workspace to `C:/workspace` instead of Win 7 `Libraries`.